# adding a filter to a HAVING query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a great query that works well:

```
select distinct f.client_id
from f_accession_daily f
left join SalesDWH..TestPractices tests
on tests.ClientID=f.CLIENT_ID
where tests.ClientID is null
group by f.client_id
having max(f.received_date) between '20120601' and '20120630'
```

**I need to limit the result set to only `f.client_id` where the count(*) of that specific `f.client_id` was 40 or greater for the pervious month (namely between '20120501' and '20120530')**

here's what i tried:

```
select distinct f.client_id
from f_accession_daily f
left join SalesDWH..TestPractices tests
on tests.ClientID=f.CLIENT_ID
where tests.ClientID is null
group by f.client_id
having max(f.received_date) between '20120601' and '20120630'
) NotOrderedIn6Months
on f.CLIENT_ID=NotOrderedIn6Months.CLIENT_ID
right join
(select client_id,COUNT(*) count from F_ACCESSION_DAILY
where RECEIVED_DATE between '20120501' and '20120530'
group by CLIENT_ID
having COUNT(*)>=40
) Having40
on Having40.CLIENT_ID=f.CLIENT_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-aggregate the data for the last month (there are 31 days in May, not 30), then join into it.

```
   select f.client_id
     from f_accession_daily f
     join (
        select client_id
          from f_accession_daily
         where received_date between '20120501' and '20120531'
      group by client_id
        having count(*) >= 40
      ) A on A.client_id = f.client_id
left join SalesDWH..TestPractices tests
       on tests.ClientID=f.CLIENT_ID
    where tests.ClientID is null
 group by f.client_id
   having max(f.received_date) between '20120601' and '20120630';
```

Note also that you won't need DISTINCT when you already have GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
AND f.client_id IN
(SELECT client_id FROM F_ACCESSION_DAILY
WHERE RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN '20120501' AND '20120530'
GROUP BY client_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 40)
```

to the where clause of you original query.